# Renaming columns in a large list of dataframes based on value in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a large list of 24 elements, all data frames with the same columns. I'll give a simplified example of the data here:

```
df1 <- data.frame(location = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123),
              value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
              rainfall = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))


df2 <- data.frame(location = c(246, 246, 246, 246, 246),
              value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
              rainfall = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

df3 <- data.frame(location = c(369, 369, 369, 369, 369),
              value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
              rainfall = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

alldfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to create a new data frame, which contains the rainfall values for the different locations (1, 2, and 3) and looks like this:

| Rainfall.123 | Rainfall.246 | Rainfall.369 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

My data set is much bigger than this, and has different column names etc, so I need to program this so that it reads the value from the 'location' column and renames the 'rainfall' column based on this value. I want to create boxplots with the rainfall values, and need them to have different names in order to do this.

I have tried:

```
alldfs <- lapply(
  alldfs, function(df) {
    df$rainfall %>% rename_with( ~ "Rainfall",paste(df$location))
  }
)
```

But this doesn't work - I feel like there must be a simple solution that I'm missing...

Thank you!

Comment: What should happen to the `value` column?

Comment: @MartinGal I don't really need it, but the answer below uses it for an index which is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack the datasets on top of one another using `bind_rows()` and then reshape the data:

```r
bind_rows(alldfs) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = "value", names_from = location, 
                values_from = rainfall, names_prefix = "rainfall.")
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  value rainfall.123 rainfall.246 rainfall.369
  <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 a                1            1            1
2 b                1            1            1
3 c                0            0            0
4 d                0            0            0
5 e                1            1            1
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but it bases it on the length of the dataframe, rather than the value in the 'location' column. I'll edit the question to make it clearer what I want.

Comment: I see; I think that your best bet would be to use `pivot_wider()` rather than `lapply()`. I edited the answer to show how I would do that.